# Get same two-factor code, like I received in my App Authy in JAVA

Tags: java, api, automation, one-time-password, authy

I want use API of BitSkins.com, but they use two-factor codes through Authy. For request on BitSkins I need API_key and code.
By link: https://bitskins.com/api/, maybe wrote about it, but they haven't solution for JAVA.

```
https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_account_balance/?api_key=I_KNOW_IT&code=**CODE_IN_PHONE_GENERATE_AUTOMATICALY**
```

How to receive same code **CODE_IN_PHONE_GENERATE_AUTOMATICALY**, like I received in my Authy application on my phone?

Comment: Hey i was having the same same trouble last night. I am travelling right now, i will post the answer as soon as i get to my office!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issues as OP. Just Googling stuff for 5 minutes solved that.

I am using [this](https://github.com/j256/java-two-factor-auth) little API here.

My implementation might quite a bit different from you as I am doing this as a part of very big project and [my company](http://sarvika.com/) is funding this.

---

## Spring Implementation

In our application, the process is automated and we are using Spring Framework. I have created a bean which is nothing but a `Thread` that runs indefinitely and generates the Authy code (same as shown in the mobile phone).

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

import com.sarvika.commonslib.util.StringUtil;
import com.j256.totp.TwoFactorAuthUtil;

public class Authy2FactorThreadBean extends Thread implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Authy2FactorThreadBean.class);

    private String base32Secret;
    private String keyId;

    private String qrCodeImageUrl;
    private String code;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            TwoFactorAuthUtil twoFactorAuthUtil = new TwoFactorAuthUtil();

            qrCodeImageUrl = twoFactorAuthUtil.qrImageUrl(keyId, base32Secret);
            code = twoFactorAuthUtil.generateCurrentNumber(base32Secret);

            while (true) {
                code = twoFactorAuthUtil.generateCurrentNumber(base32Secret);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {

        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(base32Secret) || StringUtil.isEmpty(keyId)) {
            logger.warn("Base32 Secret or Key ID not provided. 2Factor Codes will not be generated!!!!!");
            return;
        }

        logger.info("Starting 2Factor Generation Thread...");
        start();

    }   

    public String getBase32Secret() {
        return base32Secret;
    }

    public void setBase32Secret(String base32Secret) {
        this.base32Secret = base32Secret;
    }

    public String getKeyId() {
        return keyId;
    }

    public void setKeyId(String keyId) {
        this.keyId = keyId;
    }

    public String getQrCodeImageUrl() {
        return qrCodeImageUrl;
    }

    public void setQrCodeImageUrl(String qrCodeImageUrl) {
        this.qrCodeImageUrl = qrCodeImageUrl;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

Then you create a bean like this:

```
<bean id="authy2FactorThreadBean" class="Authy2FactorThreadBean">
    <!-- twofactor.secret is the Secret shown by the Bitskins when you are authorizing your phone -->
    <property name="base32Secret" value="${twofactor.secret}"/>

    <!-- twofactor.key is the name of the key which can be displayed by the authenticator program -->
    <property name="keyId" value="${twofactor.key}"/>
</bean>
```

And pass it around wherever you want the generated two-factor code.

---

## Non-Spring Implementation

Please see [this](https://github.com/j256/java-two-factor-auth/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/totp/TwoFactorAuthExample.java) little example by the API Author.